# WPF4 JumpList Missing when launched from Program Files

Tags: c#, wpf, jump-list

I have a [very simple application](http://clipboardeditor.codeplex.com/) that I'm adding jumplist support to.

A few days ago I was happy and I called it version 1. So I copied it to `c:\program files\clipboard editor\clipboardeditor.exe` and ran it. Great. Pinned it to my taskbar, even better.

Now I'm adding a jumplist to go right to the common formats skipping the UI altogether. I've written it all--it works! Built as Release, copied it over the old exe in program files and launch it--no jump list. I've pinned and unpinned and rebooted and done everything I can think of.

It feels like Explorer is caching the jump list for the exe from Program files but my Google skills are failing me. Any suggestions?

My (working from not-program files) XAML looks like:

```
<JumpTask Title="Text Only" Arguments="text" IconResourcePath="%WINDIR%\System32\imageres.dll"  IconResourceIndex="14"/>
<JumpTask Title="Image Only" Arguments="image" IconResourcePath="%WINDIR%\System32\imageres.dll"  IconResourceIndex="16"/>
<JumpTask Title="HTML Only" Arguments="html" IconResourcePath="%WINDIR%\System32\imageres.dll"  IconResourceIndex="20"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that I was building with platform `x86` and copying to `Program Files`. Once I copied to `Program Files (x86)` or built as `Any CPU` the problem went away.